# General form of a function sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, functions

I've problem with defining a general form of a function sequence. From the begining - last time, I was wondering, how simple function defined by other functions iside can be defined. So let we say, that we've a mentioned function F(x):
$$F(x) = \frac{c \cdot a_{0}+f_{1}(x)}{a_{0}+ c \cdot f_{1}(x)}$$
where function $f_{1}(x)$ is:
$$f_{1}(x) = \frac{c \cdot a_{1}+f_{2}(x)}{a_{1}+ c \cdot f_{2}(x)}$$
$f_{2}(x)$:
$$f_{2}(x) = \frac{c \cdot a_{2}+f_{3}(x)}{a_{2}+ c \cdot f_{3}(x)}$$
and so on, until the last element:
$$f_{n}(x) = \frac{c \cdot a_{n}+f_{n+1}(x)}{a_{n}+ c \cdot f_{n+1}(x)}$$

As an example, if I substitute $f_{1,2}(x)$ to F(x), I'll get:

$$F(x) = \frac{c \cdot a_{0}+\frac{c \cdot a_{1}+\frac{c \cdot a_{2}+f_{3}(x)}{a_{2}+ c \cdot f_{3}(x)}}{a_{1}+ c \cdot \frac{c \cdot a_{2}+f_{3}(x)}{a_{2}+ c \cdot f_{3}(x)}}}{a_{0}+ c \cdot \frac{c \cdot a_{1}+\frac{c \cdot a_{2}+f_{3}(x)}{a_{2}+ c \cdot f_{3}(x)}}{a_{1}+ c \cdot \frac{c \cdot a_{2}+f_{3}(x)}{a_{2}+ c \cdot f_{3}(x)}}}$$

My first idea was to use recursive method to find general form of F(x) function, however I don't see any pattern, and I got lost with that. To be clear - as the final result, I want to find general equation F(x) which will have character of rational function (so it will have the numerator, and the denominator), dependent on n parameter. How can I find it ? Could you suggest me some methods to solve this problem ?

Best Regards,
E.

Comment: I feel like this function $F$ is misdefined, because the set of functions $f$ has no term that is properly defined. Does the limit of $f$ when $n$ goes to infinity equal zero?

Comment: Well, I don't checked limit of f functions, however it shouldn't goes to zero. Furthermore, I made a mistake - functions: F(x), $f_{1}$, $f_{2}$, and $f_{n}$ are defined for c parameter changes NOT x (so we have F(c), $f_{1}(c)$, ...)

Comment: What if... I'll try implement here the Linear fractional transformation theory ? Will this work ?